# Can I travel to Mexico with a single-entry Schengen visa?

Tags: international-travel, schengen-visas, spain, mexico

Can I travel with a single-entry Schengen visa to Mexico? Do I need to visit a Schengen county before going to Mexico?

Comment: According to https://www.inm.gob.mx/gobmx/word/index.php/paises-requieren-visa-para-mexico/  the holder of a ‘valid and current’ Schengen visa can enter Mexico (Visa válida y vigente de Canadá, de los Estados Unidos de América, Japón, el Reino Unido de la Gran Bretaña e Irlanda del Norte o cualquiera de los países que integran el Espacio Schengen). Not sure about the 2nd part of your question

Comment: If you visit a Schengen country before going to Mexico, the visa is no longer valid, so that would be a no.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I travel with single entry Schengen visa to Mexico,

Yes. According to https://www.inm.gob.mx/gobmx/word/index.php/paises-requieren-visa-para-mexico/ a visa national who is the holder of a valid and current Schengen visa can enter Mexico.

> and do I need to visit a Schengen county before going to Mexico

As commented by @Leaderboard, If you visit a Schengen country with a single entry visa before going to Mexico, the visa is no longer valid, so that would be a no.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://consulmex.sre.gob.mx/reinounido/index.php/es/contenido/92-tourist-visa The visa needs to be issued for multiple entries so I don't know if a single entry visa is valid.